# UITableView not loading but array is populated

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I would like to populate with data via a WebAPI.  I have everything set up and I can verify that data is returned in JSON format.  What I don't understand is why I see that data in my array printed out several times when I use NSLog and also how do I assign this data to the UITableView.  I was able to populate the table from the viewDidLoad method but these are hard-coded values.  I want to populate the grid with data that is returned from my call to the remote server.  This data is available to me in my didReceiveData delegate.  What am I doing wrong here?

I have this code in my MasterViewControler.h

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate> {

NSMutableArray *dataArray;
NSMutableArray *categoryNames;
```

}

Here is an abridged version of what I have in my MasterViewController.m file

```
NSMutableData* receivedData;
NSString* hostName;
NSInteger portNumber = 9999;
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary;
NSInteger maxRetryCount = 5;
int count = 0;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[data length]);
NSError *error = nil;
// Get the JSON data from the website

id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

    for (NSArray *item in result)
        [dataArray addObject:item];

    NSLog(@"%@", dataArray);
}
else {
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;

    for(NSDictionary *item in jsonDictionary)
        NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
}}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

hostName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"12.34.56.78"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%i%@", hostName, portNumber, @"/api/products"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval: 2]; 

NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewItem)];  //insertNewObject
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//[dataArray addObject:@"Apple"];
//[dataArray addObject:@"Mango"];
//[dataArray addObject:@"Orange"];}
```

Instead of populating the dataArray here I was trying to populate it in the didReceiveData delegate.  The dataArray will be allocated but it is almost like I have to reload the UITableView to see the values.  I tried that at the end of didReceiveData but I received an error.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` are set.

Once the array is populated (in your case, at the end of `-(void)connection:didReceiveData:`) you'd call `[tableView reloadData]` to refresh the table.

Then you'd set your cell in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // If your array is an array of strings, change if applicable
    NSString *string = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:string];

}
```

Comment: Are these set in didReceiveData?

Comment: My cellForRowAtIndexPath is very similar

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    return cell;
}

Comment: I still don't understand exactly where UITableViewDataSource or UITableViewDelegate are set.  Would you explain this please?

Comment: If you're loading the view from an nib, you can connect the data source and delegate in interface builder, but otherwise (if your UITableView is called tableView) you can set `self.tableView.dataSource = self` and `self.tableView.delegate = self`

Comment: My header file already has this: <UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate>

Comment: I tried adding the three lines below to the end of didReceiveData but I am getting a new error in cellForRowAtIndexPath.                                        [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: Change `<UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate>` to  `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>` and add `self.tableView.dataSource = self` and `self.tableView.delegate = self` to your viewDidLoad or your init method.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement UITableView's UITableViewDataSource protocol, and then assign itself as the dataSource. Then implement cellForRowAtIndexPath:, which is where you actually use your model array to initialize the cells. When your data is ready, call reloadData on the table view.

Comment: From what I understand the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called as soon as viewDidLoad ends.  If I am waiting for didReceiveData to complete then my cellForRowAtIndexPath will not have any values in the dataArray, which is the error I am getting.  I need answers please not a rehashing of what I have already explained is done.  If I addObject(s) to my array that I already have when the application loads I see them without issue.  I want to do SOMETHING DIFFERENT.  I want to take the data from the JSON that is returned to my application and use THAT DATA to populate my UITableView.  Make sense?

Comment: So, I commented out the line that was causing the error in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  This line was looking for something the row index of the dataArray which was not populated at this point.  This allowed me to populate the table view by calling [self.tableView reloadData]; from the bottom of didReceiveData.

Comment: Nope, I had to uncomment this later.  I solved it on my own.  I asked for some clarification and unfortunately didn't get it. :-(

Comment: Good for you, sorry no help :-)

Comment: iOS is different from C# (.NET) but I am figuring this stuff out, slowly but surely.